# Cross-compile from x86-64 Ubuntu to Windows with clang++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, clang, x86-64

The program is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

}
```

Everything goes OK if I use

```
clang++ helloworld.cpp
```

But when I try to cross-compile it for Windows I get an error:

```
clang++ helloworld.cpp -target x86_64-win32
helloworld.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
^
1 error generated.
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: What host OS are you cross-compiling from, and did you install the cross-headers for Windows?

Comment: @Peter The host OS is Ubuntu. How do I install and use cross-headers?

Comment: You might have better success if you looked for the answer in https://askubuntu.com/